# Como parsear json() r.json() not working ! AgAiN

Tags: python-3.x, json, python-requests

estoy trabajando con requests de python

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
import requests

url = https://etc etc

r = requests.get(url)

print(r.json())
```

y me da el siguiente error:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "REQUEST_HELP2.py", line 25, in 
    print('joder',r.json())
  File "C:\Users\jotas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jotas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\jotas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\jotas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)**

cuando hago otros requests a la pagina obtengo estos resultados, y por lo que a mi me parece las condiciones son optimas para obtener un json:

status_code:200

apparent_encoding:ascii

connection:requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter object at 0x038422D0

encoding:UTF-8

json:bound method Response.json of Response [200]

He leido y tratado varias sugerencias que he leido como revisar si es utf 8, que en vez de utilizar r.json utilizar r.json() y que esto ultimo es lo recomendado y no otras cosas como r.load etc, pero no se como implementarlo..espero ayuda. El json está ahí mismo.

Gracias por su tiempo

Comment: Sería bueno que agregaras el contenido de la respuesta (`print(r.content`)), si por algo no puedes  completa, al menos el inicio. Éste tipo de errores suele indicar o respuesta vacía, problema de encoding, JSON malformado o truncado o la respuesta no es realmente un JSON sino xml/html por ejemplo, pero sin más información y sin poder reproducir el problema va a ser difícil poder acertar con la causa. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que no retorne un json, o que este muy pesado, podrias verificar si retorna un json, puedes guardar el contenido de la respuesta.

```
open('respuesta.json','w').write(r.content)
```

Por otro lado si la codificacion de la respuesta no es utf-8 y la quieres establecer a utf-8 seria establecer la codificacion:

```
r.encoding
```

retornara la codificacion, para cambiar la codificacion:

```
r.encoding = 'utf-8'
```

prodras ver la respuesta en utf-8 usando:

```
r.text
```